# Time Capsule - Home made - OpenWrt router with usb disk acting as airport wireless device

Tags: dd-wrt, openwrt, time-capsule

I want to remove need of connecting my Time Capsule usb disk directly to usb on my macbook. I don't need any other functionality which [Apple Time Capsule](http://www.apple.com/timecapsule/) offer.

Ideas/Questions

1. Is it possible to use my router with connected usb disk( formated as Time Capsule ) and installed OpenWRT as network Time Capsule?
2. May I use Samba share as Time Capsule disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Samba. Time Machine will only talk to AFP shares. Fortunately, the Linux package netatalk provides AFP services much as Samba provides SMB services. See [this post](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=131001) for some suggestions as to how it might work with OpenWRT.